# How SOAP server identify me afte login?

Tags: php, authentication, soap

i just started to working with soap objects and faced interesting situation.

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

try 
{
    $exampleService = new SoapClient("http://www.blabla.com/service/service.asmx?WSDL",array("trace"=>true));   
    $response = $exampleService->SetCategory(array("Name"=>"lorem-ipsum","Code"=>"lorem","MainCategory"=>0,"Visible"=>"Lorem Ipsum"));
    var_dump($response);

} 
catch (Exception $exc) 
{ 
    echo "Soap Error: " . $exc->getMessage();
    var_dump($exampleService->__getLastResponse());
}
```

this code adding category. but if i send this request before authorization it says "Unidentified User" or something like that.

then i tried this

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

try 
{
    $exampleService = new SoapClient("http://www.blabla.com/service/service.asmx?WSDL",array("trace"=>true));   
    $authdata = array("Auth_Code"=>"***","username"=>"***","password"=>"***");
    $response = $exampleService->Auth($authdata);

    $response = $exampleService->SetCategory(array("Name"=>"lorem-ipsum","Code"=>"lorem","MainCategory"=>0,"Visible"=>"Lorem Ipsum"));

    var_dump($response);
} 
catch (Exception $exc) 
{ 
    echo "Soap Error: " . $exc->getMessage();
    var_dump($exampleService->__getLastResponse());
}
```

worked succesfully and added category.

here is the tricky part; then i keep working on the project and luckily send first request again (without any authentication data) and it has worked also. but i didnt sent/set any username/password.

how soap server identify me (my server)? is there a logic like browsers COOKIE? i printed $exampleService->__cookie and its NULL ?

please enlighten me. i hope blabla.com doesnt identify users ip based :)